# How do you test for an exception that is inside of a private method, which is used by a public void?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

As the title says, I am testing that an exception is thrown inside a private method, which is then accessed by a public void. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the exception caught by that public Method? If not it should just bubble up and can be tested like any other exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Assert.Throws](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.Throws) to check that an exception is thrown. If the exception is not thrown then the test will fail:

```
var foo = new Foo();
Assert.Throws<MyException>(() => foo.DoSomething());
```

This test requires that `MyException` is thrown. If another exception (even one derived from `MyException`) is thrown then the test will fail.

If you want to test for an exception or anything derived from that exception then you can use [Assert.Catch](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.Catch) :

```
var foo = new Foo();
Assert.Catch<MyException>(() => foo.DoSomething());
```